# How to average an off-set array

Tags: python

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
A = [.36, .4, .43, .48, .53, .58, .63, .68, .72, .77, .82, .86, .93, .95, .97, .99, 1, 0.99, .97, .95, .92, .88, .85, .80, .76, .71, .66, .61, .56, .51, .47, .43, .40]
```

I want to be able to take the value to the left and right of 1, and find their average, and then extend +1 in each direction of 1. So that my new array is

```
 A =[1, (.99 +.99)/2, (.97 + .97)/2, (.95 + .95)/2, ......, (.36 + .40)/2]
```

Initially I was trying to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

A = [.36, .4, .43, .48, .53, .58, .63, .68, .72, .77, .82, .86, .93, .95, .97, .99, 1, 0.99, .97, .95, .92, .88, .85, .80, .76, .71, .66, .61, .56, .51, .47, .43, .40]
A = np.sort(A)
A = list(itertoools.chain.from_iterable[i]*n for i in [sum(A[i:i+n])/n for i in range(0, len(A)),n)]))
A = A[1::2]
A = A[::-1]
```

So what this does is re-order my list from least to greatest (sort), and then take the average of each value next to it (the `iter`tools and `A[1::2]` command), then re-order backwards (the `A[::-1]` line). But i've found this does that incorrectly, more particularly in the average section due to the resort. It re-sorts it properly, but then that causes the average to be taken improperly as `.4` moves next to `.36`, and then I have two `0.43s` right next to each other after that, which leads my tail values to have incorrect averages.

I'd be happy to supply any more information for any particular questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you sorting in the first place? Isn't the original list already sorted on the left and right of `1`?

Comment: Is `1` guarantee to be in the middle of the list? What should happen if it isn't?

Comment: I wasn't aware of a way to do this initially, and then realized that my "brilliant idea" didn't work quite the way i'd wanted. 1 isn't always the center for other lists in this case. It is for most of them, but not all of them.

Comment: If 1 isn't in the middle, how are the averages calculated for the excess on the longer side? Or should it always start with the middle element rather than 1? What if there are an even number of elements?

Comment: So if 1 isn't in the middle, it is either 1 up or 1 down from the middle. The problem is always odd.

Comment: And what is the result supposed to be if it's not exactly in the middle? There will be an extra element at one end that isn't matched.

Comment: So it seems that for the 2 data sets where that's the case, the data is disregarded. So to re-answer your question: 1 is always in the middle, and the set is always odd. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple take on this:

```
A = [.36, .4, .43, .48, .53, .58, .63, .68, .72, .77, .82, .86, .93, .95, .97, .99,
     1, 0.99, .97, .95, .92, .88, .85, .80, .76, .71, .66, .61, .56, .51, .47, .43, .40]

center = A.index(1)
right = A[center + 1:]
A.reverse()
left = A[center + 1:]

out = [round((l + r) / 2, 2) for l, r in zip(left, right)]
out.insert(0, 1) # or A[center]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0.99, 0.97, 0.95, 0.93, 0.87, 0.83, 0.79, 0.74, 0.7, 0.65, 0.59, 0.55, 0.49, 0.45, 0.42, 0.38]
```

I made it so it rounds each division to 2 decimals. I tried to make this as easy as possible to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [.36, .4, .43, .48, .53, .58, .63, .68, .72, .77, .82, .86, .93, .95, .97, .99, 1, 0.99, .97, .95, .92, .88, .85, .80, .76, .71, .66, .61, .56, .51, .47, .43, .40]
index = A.index(1) 
l =[]
for i in range(index + 1):
  l.append((A[index - i] +A[index + i])/2)
l
```

Gives me :

```
[1.0,
0.99,
0.97,
0.95,
0.925,
0.87,
0.835,
0.785,
0.74,
0.6950000000000001,
 0.645,
 0.595,
 0.545,
 0.495,
 0.44999999999999996,
 0.41500000000000004,
 0.38]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert A to a numpy array and then find the location of `1` using `np.where(A==1)` and index slicing either side of that and compute the average across the two arrays, with the left-hand side of 1 being reversed.

```
A = np.array(A)
i = np.where(A==1)[0][0]
left = A[:i+1][::-1]
right = A[i:]
ave = np.average([left, right], axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([1.   , 0.99 , 0.97 , 0.95 , 0.925, 0.87 , 0.835, 0.785, 0.74 ,
       0.695, 0.645, 0.595, 0.545, 0.495, 0.45 , 0.415, 0.38 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that 1 is in the centre of `A`, and that the length is odd, is is straightforward. If you need to handle `A` being somewhere else, for example `A = [.5, 1, .8., .3, .1]`, then you need to decide whether you want to use just `A = [.5, 1, .8]` or `A = [0, 0, .5, 1, .8, .3, .1]`, or `A = [.1, .3, .5, 1, .8, .3, .1]`, or some other method. You might also want to think about what happens if there is not exactly one instance of 1.

For the simplest example, it's in the middle always, then.

```
A = [.36, .4, .43, .48, .53, .58, .63, .68, .72, .77, .82, .86, .93, .95, .97, .99, 1, 0.99, .97, .95, .92, .88, .85, .80, .76, .71, .66, .61, .56, .51, .47, .43, .40]
a_pos = A.index(1)
A1 = A[a_pos: 0: -1] 
A2 = A[a_pos:]
result = [round((x + y) / 2, 2) for x, y in zip(A1, A2)]
print(result)
```

If 1 is not in the middle of `A`, then one of `A1` or `A2` needs to be modified, by extending the shorter one with zeroes, or with the values taken from the longer one, or shorten the longer one to the length of the shorter one.